# how to rename apk output file with agp 7.0+?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Before agp 7.0, I can rename apk file name as this:

```kotlin
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

        def date = new Date().format("yyyyMMddHHmm")

        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "${variant.name}_${date}.apk"
        }
    }
```

After agp 7.0, outputs has no outputFileName field.So how to rename with apg 7.0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly different configuration with my Android project, but it is still working with [AGP 7.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#7-1-0).
Here is what I did, using the property `archivesBaseName` :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 32
buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx.yyy"
    minSdkVersion 21 
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 86
    versionName "1.12.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", "myapp-$versionName")
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
...
```

It results in having two APK (variants) :

- ./app/build/outputs/apk/release/myapp-1.12.0-release.apk
- ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/myapp-1.12.0-debug.apk

I hope it can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen that. I did't use the way since I want name according to  variant's info.

Comment: OK. I've just seen that starting with AGP 7.0 we can go further by using the AGP build API : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SB4QlngQQW0

Comment: And I just discovered this nice repository : [Android Plugin for Gradle cookbook](https://github.com/android/gradle-recipes)

Comment: To be complete, the blog post explaining all this : [Gradle and AGP Build APIs: Taking your plugin to the next step!](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gradle-and-agp-build-apis-taking-your-plugin-to-the-next-step-95e7bd1cd4c9)

Comment: I had read this blogs and api doc. But I  have not found api to do this.